# Separating dot values from list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a csv file. In a particular column, say c3, I have data formated with dots. For example, the columns contain:

```
c3={[12.14.01],[12.14.02],[12.14.03],[12.14.04].....}
```

I want to separate these into the three parts: 12 14 01, individually, and put these back into the same csv file, appended as a particular column. Example:

```
column10=12 column11=14 columnn12=01  append row 1
column10=12 column11=14 columnn12=02 append  row 2
column10=12 column11=14 columnn12=03 append  row 3
```

How can do that using python?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a string, you can split it on the `.`:

```
>>> '12.14.01'.split('.')
['12', '14', '01']
```

From there on out it is trivial to construct a new list that you pass back to a `csv.writer()` to write to a new file.

Comment: Since it in csv file how to extract particular column data and then separate it out and paste in empty column